# Documentation for Custom Ops in Tensorflow to ONNX

Tags: python, tensorflow, onnx, tensorrt

I am attempting to convert a trained Tensorflow 2.5 SavedModel into ONNX, with the hopes of eventually being able to convert the ONNX model into TensorRT to accelerate inference. For background, it is a modified version of the [3DFeatNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.09413) ([GitHub](https://github.com/yewzijian/3DFeatNet)) paper that I adapted from TensorFlow 1 to TensorFlow 2.

My model requires the use of custom ops in Tensorflow, which run only on GPU. These ops are registered using `tf.load_op_library()`, which links to the `.so` file generated after compiling the CUDA/C++ code used to implement the op.

When I attempt to convert the SavedModel using the below command, the custom ops are not registered, and the resulting ONNX graph does not show the custom ops when I view the file in Netron.

```sh
python tf2onnx_convert.py --saved-model path/to/model \ 
--output path/to/output \
--load_op_libraries path/to/.so_files \
--verbose --rename-inputs $INPUTS \
--rename-outputs $OUTPUTS
```

Thus, I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to register the `.so` files in ONNX without needing to adapt the CUDA/C++ code to the ONNX custom op API? If not, are there any guides on how to do so?
2. Will I need to undergo a similar process in registering custom ops when I convert my model to TensorRT?

Thank you in advance! Will edit this post if any more info is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to answer my own question after tinkering around a bit by adding the `--custom-ops` flag to the `tf2onnx.convert` command.

My eventual command became

```sh
python tf2onnx_convert.py --saved-model path/to/model \ 
--output path/to/output/output_graph.onnx \
--load_op_libraries path/to/.so_files \
--custom-ops QueryBallPoint,GroupPoint \
--rename-inputs $INPUTS \
--rename-outputs $OUTPUTS
```

(where QueryBallPoint and GroupPoint are specific to the model I am using, and could be changed as per the given module that is in your use case)

Viewing the graph produced in Netron `netron path/to/output/output_graph.onnx` shows something I expected, so I'm closing the issue now.

I would still appreciate feedback on my method, and an answer to my second question. Thanks!